# How can i filter my json data by the numbers selected in my select tags

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Let's say that i have this json file :

```
[
  {
    "restaurantName":"name1",
    "address":"restaurant1 address",
    "lat":lat1,
    "long":long1,
    "ratings":[
       {
          "stars":4,
          "comment":"good"
       },
       {
          "stars":5,
          "comment":"excellent"
       }
     ]
  },
  {
    "restaurantName":"name2",
    "address":"restaurant2 address",
    "lat":lat2,
    "long":long2,
    "ratings":[
       {
          "stars":4,
          "comment":"good"
       },
       {
          "stars":3,
          "comment":"ok"
       }
     ]
  } 
]
```

And this html code:

```
<select id="s1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="btn">filter</button>
```

The problem is that i can't find a way to filter this data and get the restaurants list that have a star rating between the two numbers selected in the select tags.

Comment: So first i think you want the avg of the ratings for each resturant. If you done with that you can use the filter method

Comment: Ok, i will look into that, thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `Array.reduce` to sum the stars values, the function `Array.filter` to check for the `from-to` rating interval.

```js
let data = [  {    "restaurantName":"name1",    "address":"restaurant1 address",    "lat":1,    "long":1,    "ratings":[       {          "stars":4,          "comment":"good"       },       {          "stars":5,          "comment":"excellent"       }     ]  },  {    "restaurantName":"name2",    "address":"restaurant2 address",    "lat":1,    "long":1,    "ratings":[       {          "stars":4,          "comment":"good"       },       {          "stars":3,          "comment":"ok"       }     ]  } ],
    ratingFrom = 3, // from s1 select
    ratingTo = 4, // from s2 select
    result = data.filter(d => {
      let avg = d.ratings.reduce((a, r) => a + r.stars, 0) / d.ratings.length;
      return avg >= ratingFrom && avg <= ratingTo;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest to check the docs on [Array.filter(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) and  [Array.reduce(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
In the example below you can see a possible solution to your problem.

You can calculate the average value of your ratings by summing up the values of stars using [Array.reduce(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), afterwards you can compare the calculated value with the selected values in your `<select>`, that's where the [Array.filter(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) is coming in, in short - this function will return you a new Array containing the elements which are meeting the pre-defined condition (in our case it is `avgRating >= minRating && avgRating <= maxRating;`).

The shortest solution has been already provided by @Ele, my example below introduces an additional [Array.map(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map), which is not obligatory here. Nevertheless, in case you were questioning what it does - that additional `map` function will return me a new Array containing only the ratings itself, in case of `restaurant1` it would be `[4, 5]`

```js
const data = [{
    "restaurantName": "name1",
    "address": "restaurant1 address",
    "lat": 51.43434,
    "long": 51.43434,
    "ratings": [{
        "stars": 4,
        "comment": "good"
      },
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "comment": "excellent"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "restaurantName": "name2",
    "address": "restaurant2 address",
    "lat": 51.43434,
    "long": 51.43434,
    "ratings": [{
        "stars": 4,
        "comment": "good"
      },
      {
        "stars": 3,
        "comment": "ok"
      }
    ]
  }
];

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const filteredRestaurants = data.filter(entry => {
    const ratings = entry.ratings;
    const avgRating = ratings
      .map(rating => rating.stars)
      .reduce((prev, next) => {
        return prev + next;
      }, 0) / ratings.length;
    const minRating = document.getElementById('s1').value;
    const maxRating = document.getElementById('s2').value;

    return avgRating >= minRating && avgRating <= maxRating;
  });
  console.log(filteredRestaurants);
});
```

```html
<select id="s1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="btn">filter</button>
```